# How can I pass a form argument to a jquery variable and display it´s results?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, youtube, playlist

I not into programing so I having some dificulting getting something to work. I've managed to come up with a working jquery that pulls a youtube playlist by its ID and displays it.

The code the holds the playlist is

```
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL60038DE2D1B1A21C?v=2&max-results=5&alt=json&callback=?';
```

Here is the full code.... http://jsfiddle.net/tqWxc/814/

Everytime I need to pull a diferent playlist I need to manually edit the code and chenage the playlist ID . 
what I want to be able to do is to create a form where a user puts the playlist ID -> submit -> display the playlist content

How could I acconplish this?

Comment: How is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388788/how-can-fill-form-submit-display-results-using-the-following-script ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a variable for where the playlist should be within that string.

```
var playlistID = '12345';
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/' + playlistID + '?v=2&max-results=5&alt=json&callback=?';
```

Comment: Yep, but how could I pass the value from a form to the "var playlistID"

What I need is for the user to enter the PlaylistID into the form and when he hits Submit it will send the ID to the variable and display the code. I hope I am been clear on my explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to use a form because that would submit the page and you would essentially lose your value that was entered. Instead, you would want to create a click handler on an element (in this case a `button`) and listen for when the user clicks that button. Once they do, you want the grab the value that's in the input box and push that into the URL string for your ajax call. You could also add in some error checking logic, but below is a simple **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/eZPKb/)**:

**HTML:**

```
<input></input>
<button>submit</button>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var playlistId = "";

    $("button").on("click", function(){
      playlistId = $("input").val();
      var playlistURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/' + playlistId + '?v=2&max-results=5&alt=json&callback=?';
       console.log(playlistURL) 
      //make your ajax call with platListURL
    });
});​
```

Comment: Cool. where it says "//make your ajax call with platListURL" I should put my code is that it? I tried it doesn't work! I enter a playlist ID into the field and hit submit but nothing happens! :-( 
I probly doing sth wrong!

Comment: @Andre - Here's an update link with our code combined: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/tqWxc/826/, however, the videos don't seem to be appearing for me and I'm actually at work currently and don't have a whole lot of time. If you get a chance, take a look and if you notice the issue post it here.